# How to mock an error callback for a BackboneJS model (in destroy)?

Tags: backbone.js, callback, jasmine, marionette, backbone-model

Given the following [BackboneJS 1.1.0 model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) / [MarionetteJS 1.0.4 module](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/v1.0.4/docs/marionette.application.module.md):

```
MyApp.module('Product', function(Product, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {    
  Product.Model = Backbone.Model.extend({

    destroy: function() {
      console.log("Product.destroy()");
      return Backbone.Model.prototype.destroy.apply(this, arguments);
    }

  });
});
```

How would you **simulate** that the [destroy function](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-destroy) **fails** so you can test the associated behavior (such as a user notification alert message)? I use [Jasmine 1.3.0](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/tree/v1.3.0) for testing in this project.

Answer (score 1):

if you wanna test the error callback...you can mock the server response in jasmine by using http://sinonjs.org/

define your server in a before block:

```
var server, aProductInstance;

beforeEach(function() {
  server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
  aProductInstance = new Product.Model({id: 999});
});
```

restore it after each test:

```
afterEach(function() {
  server.restore();
});
```

in your test, use respondWith method to return a non-200 response

```
server.respondWith(method, url, response);
```

like so

```
describe("fail to destroy", function() {
  it("calls the error callback", function() {
    server.respondWith("DELETE", "/products/destroy", [500, { "Content-Type": "application/json" }, '{ "error": "bad request" }']);

    //call the method
    aProductInstance.destroy();

    //send the response
    server.respond();

    //now write your tests to see if error callback is called.
  });
});
```

Comment: Do you see any chance I can mock the response of the **client-side** `Product` model without involving the server?

Comment: this method does not involve a real server.

Comment: Understood. Nevertheless, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: if you dont wanna use any library, you can just stub the $.ajax method. like so:  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/testing-ajax-event-handlers-using-jasmine-spies.html#fbid=zB_U4LUeh3S